# How to Nest a For Loop to Color all Cells White Below the Diagonal

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, excel-formula, nested-for-loop

Workbook Breakdown:

I have two sheets: "3 - Task Listing" and "5 - Task Compatibility"

In the "3 - Task Listing" sheet there is a list of Task Names in Column B starting in cell 15.

In the "5 - Task Compatibility" sheet I am pulling the list of names from "3 - Task Listing" using an array formula into a row starting in Cell D9 and a column starting in Cell B11.

So, where those two lists match up Cell D11,E12,F13, etc. I have it filling those cells dark grey and writing the name from the list creating a diagonal line of greyed out cells. That is working perfectly. However, what I still need to do is to make it turn all of the cells below that diagonal white down to the last row with a Task name in Column B. Currently, the code below is turning the entire column B below the diagonal white because the array formula is causing there to be a 0 in each row past the last cell with a value.

Additionally, I need to find a way to nest another loop so that it then turns the cells white in each column below the diagonal not just Column B.

Also, I have the CL variable looking at the list of names in the "3 - Staff Listing" sheet and the list stops after Clinic 5. However, it seems to be adding zeros to the end and I am not sure why?

The first image below is what the Code is currently doing. The image after is what I am trying to achieve.

If anyone has any suggestions about how to modify this code to achieve the second picture I would really appreciate the help. I feel like I am so close but I just can't quite get this last part to work.

[image]

[image]

```
 Sub Gen_Grid()

 Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Range("D11:EZ1000").ClearContents

 With Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Range("D11:EZ1000")
     .Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
     .Borders.ColorIndex = 15
 End With

 Dim CL As Long, i As Integer, y As Integer, k As Integer

 CL = Worksheets("3 - Task Listing").Range("B15").End(xlDown).Row

 
 i = 11
 y = 4
 
 For k = 1 To CL
    
     With Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Cells(i, y)
          .Interior.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
          .Borders.ColorIndex = 48
     End With
     
    With Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Range("D12:D" & Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
          .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
          .Borders.ColorIndex = 48
          .FillDown
     End With
    
    
     Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Cells(i, y) = Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Range("B" & i).Value
     
     i = i + 1
     y = y + 1
    
 Next k

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's getting late here so this may not be the best code but basically you do need a nested loop now so it should be like this:

```
Sub Gen_Grid()

     Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Range("D11:EZ1000").ClearContents
    
     With Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Range("D11:EZ1000")
         .Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
         .Borders.ColorIndex = 15
     End With
    
     Dim CL As Integer, i As Integer, y As Integer, k As Integer, j As Integer, y1 As Integer
     
     CL = 2
     
     i = 11
     y = 4
     
     For k = 1 To CL
        
         With Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Cells(i, y)
              .Interior.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
              .Borders.ColorIndex = 48
         End With
         
         y1 = 4
         
         For j = 1 To k
         
            With Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Cells(i + 1, y1)
               .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
               .Borders.ColorIndex = 48
            End With
         
            y1 = y1 + 1
         
         Next j
        
         Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Cells(i, y) = Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Range("B" & i).Value
         
         i = i + 1
         y = y + 1
        
     Next k

 End Sub
```

*EDIT*

Will leave the original code in place, but this is probably a bit better:

```
Sub Gen_Grid()

     Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Range("D11:EZ1000").ClearContents
    
     With Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Range("D11:EZ1000")
         .Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
         .Borders.ColorIndex = 15
     End With
    
     Dim i As Integer, y As Integer, k As Integer, j As Integer, y1 As Integer
     
     Const i0 = 11, y0 = 4, CL = 2
     
     
     i = i0
     y = y0
     
     For k = 1 To CL
        
         With Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Cells(i, y)
              .Interior.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
              .Borders.ColorIndex = 48
         End With
         

         
         With Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility")
            With Range(.Cells(i + 1, y0), .Cells(i + 1, y0 + k - 1))
               .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
               .Borders.ColorIndex = 48
            End With
        End With
        
         Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Cells(i, y) = Worksheets("5 - Task Compatibility").Range("B" & i).Value
         
         i = i + 1
         y = y + 1
        
     Next k
     
     Debug.Print (Worksheets("3 - Task Listing").Range("B15").End(xlDown).Row)

 End Sub
```

Comment: Could have just  used a range rather than an inner loop but it will do for now

Comment: do you know why when I replace CL with CL = Worksheets("3 - Task Listing").Range("B15").End(xlDown).Row it gives me 14 extra rows? There is no data in the cells could it be a formatting issue?

Comment: It was because that gave the value of the last row with data I needed to subtract the starting row and it works perfectly now thank you!

Comment: It's because Worksheets("3 - Task Listing").Range("B15").End(xlDown).Row gives the row in the sheet where the last line of data is  then you have to subtract 14 to get the number of rows of data. You can check this with Debug.Print (Worksheets("3 - Task Listing").Range("B15").End(xlDown).Row)

Comment: Ah, you spotted it. I'm afraid I made a mistake in the second version of the code which means that it only works when the active sheet is "5 - Task Compatibility"  - will post amended code.